# Derivative of tr$(WD^{-2})$ wrt positive diagonal matrix $D$, where $W$ is spd

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, trace

Let $D$ be positive diagonal and $W$ be symmetric positive definite (spd). According to relation $124$ in
[matrix cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf), the derivative of tr$(WD^{-1})$ with respect to $D$ is $-D^{-1}WD^{-1}$.

How do we solve for the derivative of tr$(WD^{-2})$ with respect to $D$? I tried the Frobenius product approach, but couldn't work the steps.

Comment: are you familiar with the Frechet Derivative?

Comment: No, but will take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For convenience, define the diagonal matrix $\,V= {\rm Diag}(W) = I\odot W$

Diagonal matrices are easy to work with because they're symmetric and they commute with each other, e.g. $\,DV=VD=V^TD$

Write the function in terms of this new variable and the Frobenius product. Then find its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= {\rm Tr}(VD^{-2}) \cr&= V:D^{-2} \cr
d\phi &= V:(-2D^{-3}dD) \cr&= -2D^{-3}V:dD \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial D} &= -2D^{-3}V \cr
}$$
Note that ${\rm Tr}(VD^k) = {\rm Tr}(WD^k)$, i.e. the off-diagonal components of $W$ contribute nothing.

Comment: Thanks @greg. However, I have the following concern. Similar to the steps you provided,

$$\eqalign{
 Let \ \psi &= {\rm Tr}(VD^{-1}) \cr&= V:D^{-1} \cr
d\psi &= V:(-D^{-2}dD) \cr&= -D^{-2}V:dD \cr
\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial D} &= -D^{-2}V = -D^{-1}VD^{-1}  \cr
}$$

Meanwhile, the derivative of tr$(WD^{-1})$ with respect to $D$ is $-D^{-1}WD^{-1} \ $([matrix cookbook][1]). My concern being the inequality $-D^{-1}VD^{-1} \ne -D^{-1}WD^{-1}$.  

 [1]: https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf

Comment: First, since we're dealing with commuting (diagonal) matrices the cookbook result can be simplified to $D^{-1}VD^{-1}=D^{-2}V$. Second, the gradient of a scalar with respect to a diagonal matrix should be another diagonal matrix. Think about it, what would give rise to an off-diagonal element?

Comment: Got it! "the gradient of a scalar with respect to a diagonal matrix should be another diagonal matrix". I appreciate Greg.